# iOS v12 Https requests errors

Tags: ios, angular, express, ionic-framework, ios12

I noticed that https requests made from my Ionic Angular app on iOS v12 are failing respectively never reach my backend.

I could confirm that my app is productive and the fact that this error only occurs on iOS >= v12

When I debug in Xcode 10 beta I get the following error

> {“headers”:{“normalizedNames”:{},“lazyUpdate”:null,“headers”:{}},“status”:0,“statusText”:“Unknown Error”,“url”:null,“ok”:false,“name”:“HttpErrorResponse”,“message”:“Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error”,“error”:{“isTrusted”:true}}

My Node / Express.js backend set the following headers

```
var allowedOrigins = ["https://example.com", "http://ionic.local", "http://localhost:8080"];

 var origin = req.headers.origin;
 if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
 } else {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com");
    }

 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true") 
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description, X-Requested-With, X-ACCESS_TOKEN");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST");
```

Anyone is facing the same problem?
What did you change in your code to fix the problem for iOS v12?

P.S.:
I have opened an issue by Apple

Also here the linked subject on the Ionic forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-12-beta-preflight-requests-fail

And just in case opened an issue on the WkWebView plugin: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/112

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure but it looks like that I only face issue while querying **POST** requests respectively that I don't face it while doing GET requests...could you confirm that too?

**UPDATE 2**

In the following discussion/issue, https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/112, we are also betting on a bug in the iOS version itself. Let see if it will be corrected with the next beta version

**UPDATE 3**

`Xcode 10 beta 2` respectively `iOS 12 beta 2` released Tuesday 19th June 2018 solved my problem

Comment: This appears to be a wide spread issue. Any app using a web view to make requests appears to be broken. I'm at WWDC right now and will update with an answer once I have a response from Apple.

Comment: @InkGolem Thx, looking forward to the Apple's feedback

Comment: Thanks @InkGolem! I'm sure the whole community is interested on this one.

Comment: @InkGolem any new info about this issue? THX

Comment: Confirming that this affects only POST requests

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue! I've found that doing a call without any `Authorization` headers BEFORE doing the `Authorization` header call will make the second call work. Doing the `Authorization` call directly makes Safari not execute the request at all. Probably flagging the request as a potential security breach.

Comment: This apparently regressed in the final v12 release. Or else a similar regression occurred. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434011/how-to-fix-ios-12-safari-cors-preflight-error/52445503#52445503. But it’s been (re)fixed in v12.1, The resolved WebKit bug for it is https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188355. And the changeset for the fix is https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/234626/webkit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was an internal problem of `iOS 12 beta 1`

`Xcode 10 beta 2` respectively `iOS 12 beta 2` released Tuesday 19th June 2018 solved my problem

Comment: The fix from the Beta never made it into an official iOS 12 release.

Answer (score 3):

I'm feeling very confident that this is just a beta 1 bug with no confirmed work around. I never found an opportunity to get this verified in person while at WWDC, but it seems to be very confirmed by multiple sources including this bug on [open radar](http://www.openradar.me/40807782). I'm going to file an additional bug with Apple directly and will update my answer with any responses.

Update:
I've tested multiple devices on iOS 12 beta 2 and the issue seems to be resolved. No update on the bug filed with Apple, but I'm going to assume that it was addressed in the latest update.

Update 2:
Apple has finally closed my bug as fixed.

Answer (score -3):

Test is issue, On iOS 12, below two ways will not run into this issue

1. request with **HTTP**
2. post request with **form-data**， not with **json**. if you post with **JSON**, will trigger option request, but webkit not post this request, so cros domain failed

Comment: While these workarounds might work, I highly recommend that you do not use unencrypted web traffic nor modify the MIME type, they are there for a reason