# Fixing iOS 12 Safari Cors preflight error

Tags: ios, cors

I've started getting CORS Preflight errors from my iOS Cordova app with users on iOS 12.0x.

Researching the issue resolves back to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434011/how-to-fix-ios-12-safari-cors-preflight-error) SO post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707146/ios-v12-https-requests-errors?noredirect=1#comment91847698_50707146) post.

None of the posts gave any accepted methods of fixing the issue, rather than hoping for a 12.1 update.

That was 1 month ago and we're still on 12.01.

Is there actually any way to resolve this issue other than waiting for Apple to release a fix to production?

Answer (score -1):

Safari is adding the Origin header to the redirect. It seems entirely wrong, as some of them are not a CORS request and looks like a Bug.