# iOS Not Making Any HTTP Requests on Cordova

Tags: ios, json, http, cordova

I am having a very odd problem with a cross-platform Cordova app which works PERFECTLY fine on Android, but doesn't make any http requests for iOS.

After troubleshooting, I've found that it's actually the EXACT problem this person was running into:

[iOS v12 Https requests errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707146/ios-v12-https-requests-errors)

I'm running it on Xcode 12.4 and tried both the emulator and my own phone but it refuses to accept any requests.

Does anyone know if this could be an Xcode issue or a CORS issue?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This is because the origin cannot be set from a webview because there is no domain, so CORS will fail.
Try using [cordova-plugin-ios-xhr](https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr) and set your preferences to

```
 <preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
```